# ReDim a Dynamic-Dimension Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, treeview

So, I'm not really sure how to even title this kind of question. I've tried searching for an answer, but maybe I'm not using the right term(s). Here's the basic idea:

I have a form that contains a TreeView on the left side acting as an "Options" form. Based on the node selected in the TreeView, the appropriate Panel is displayed on the right with the controls for the selected setting. Since I'm only in the beginning of designing this form, I'm not sure how many options I'll have in the end; and thus, I'm not sure how many Panels I will have in the end.

Options Screen
[image: Options Screen]

Initially, the problem has been solved by placing all of the Panels inside a single parent Panel and creating a loop (or 4) to add all Control.Panel objects to a Control Array. This allows me to display the correct Panel based on the selected node, dynamically. The problem is...I currently only have a single sub-level (i.e. Parent and Parent-Child nodes), thus my array only needs to be 2-Dimensional. But should I decide to add another level (i.e. Parent-Child-Child), my array would need to be 3-Dimensional.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class frm_options
    Dim all_controls(,) As Control = {}         'Array of panel controls inside of panel_container.
    Private Sub frm_options_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Fill (and resize as needed) the all_controls(,) array with the panel controls based on their x,y coordinates by name.
        'Arrange ALL panels to the correct location.
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        For Each panel_control As Control In panel_container.Controls
            If TypeOf (panel_control) Is Panel Then
                'Find the total amount of x,y panels that we need to fit into our array.
                'Find x,y dimension that panel should fit into array based on name [i.e. panel_1_0(0,0), panel_1_1(0,1), panel_2_0(1,0), panel_2_1(1,1), etc.]
                Dim xy As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(panel_control.Name, "panel_(\d)*_*(\d)")
                For Each m As Match In xy
                    For Each cx As Capture In m.Groups(1).Captures
                        'For every x
                        If (cx.Value > x) Then
                            x = cx.Value
                        End If
                        For Each cy As Capture In m.Groups(2).Captures
                            'For every y in x
                            If (cy.Value > y) Then
                                y = cy.Value
                            End If
                            'Because we start our panel naming convention at 1_0, we must subtract this from our X value but not Y.
                            ReDim Preserve all_controls(x - 1, y)
                            all_controls(cx.Value - 1, cy.Value) = panel_control
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        Next
        'At this point, x = maximum x coordinates needed, y = maximum y coordinates needed and all_controls contains a list of Panels for the TreeView.
    End Sub
    Private Sub options_tree_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles options_tree.AfterSelect
        'All below examples assume there is a single parent and child node.
        'If there is a need for a child in a child node, change Level to > 1 (or however many childs needed)
        If (options_tree.SelectedNode.Level > 0) Then
            'If the selected node is a child node...
            For Each control_panel In all_controls
                If (control_panel IsNot Nothing) Then
                    If (control_panel Is all_controls(options_tree.SelectedNode.Parent.Index, options_tree.SelectedNode.Index + 1)) Then
                        control_panel.Visible = True
                    Else
                        control_panel.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Else
            'If the selected node is a parent node...
            For Each control_panel As Control In all_controls
                If (control_panel IsNot Nothing) Then
                    If (control_panel Is all_controls(options_tree.SelectedNode.Index, 0)) Then
                        control_panel.Visible = True
                    Else
                        control_panel.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Forgive my ugly coding...I'm sure there are much easier ways to achieve this - but I only code as a hobby and have never taken any courses on it. As you can see, this code allows me to add as many nodes and respective panels as needed (as long as I continue to use the right naming convention) without having to change any of my code to implement the new controls. But should I add another level to the TreeView, I will need to modify the code to use a 3-Dimensional array instead.

So in short, I'm sure there is a completely different method I should be using. If so, what would it be? Again, I want to have a code that allows me to add nodes, levels, and panels to my form without having to change the code to control these elements.

Edit: Through my research, I've looked into the Collection class. My problem with using this is that I don't think I would be able to reference which panel to display based on the Index of the selected node.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Tag` property of the tree nodes to store a reference to the form object, instead of trying to maintain a separate data structure?

Comment: I actually had not. Doing so works beautifully and reduces my code quite significantly. How have I seriously missed this property on every control?!? Thank you!